How can I disable Shift + Delete as a shortcut for "Cut"?
Across all programs I've tested this with, pressing Shift + Delete while having some text selected cuts the text, replacing whatever's already in the clipboard. How can I disable this?
This constantly messes me up, because I often use Shift+Arrow Keys to select text that I want to remove, and sometimes I let go of Shift slightly after I hit Delete and nuke my clipboard.
Ubuntu 22.04

No need to disable this feature if instead you install Extension Manager and search for and install Clipboard History.
This extension saves items you copied in to an easily accessible, searchable history panel so nothing is lost.

The actions of the likes of Ctrl+C Ctrl+V  and other such actions are inherent in the system often on an app by app basis and would be very difficult to do across the board.

"I have an evil genie that follows me around, and whenever I say the syllable 'no' in any form (know, nobody, &c), he throws my wallet in the trash."
Don't worry about disabling that feature!  Just use this handy trashcan sorter to go find your wallet every time you accidentally utter that syllable.
